# Cartesian products with a set of outer measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If I have a subset of $\mathbb R$ with Lebesgue outer measure $0$ and I take the Cartesian product with an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb R$, does the resulting set also have Lebesgue outer measure $0$ in $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: The title of your question is missing some words, no?

Comment: please see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3286/8271)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to show that it is true when the arbitrary subset is all of $\mathbb R$.  Since $\mathbb R$ is a countable union of bounded intervals, it is enough to show it is true when the arbitrary subset is a bounded interval.  So I recommend proving that it is true for $[0,1]$ first.

If $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$, you can figure out if you don't already know what the measure of $U\times [0,1]$ is.

Comment: What do you mean in that last sentence by "you can figure out"?

Comment: I mean that there is a nice expression for the measure of $U\times [0,1]$ in $\mathbb R^2$ in terms of the measure of $U$ in $\mathbb R$, and if you do not already know what this expression is, rather than immediately telling you what it is and how to show it, I recommend that you try to determine what it is and show it (i.e., "figure out" what it is).

Comment: Isn't it just the measure of $U$?  Since you just add on an interval of length one to each of the product boxes?

Comment: Right, $|I_1\times I_2|=|I_1||I_2|$, and $U$ is a countable union of disjoint intervals.  Can you see how to apply this to show that $|E|=0\implies |E\times [0,1]|=0$?

Comment: I mean, isn't it just a direct application of the formula you just posted?

Comment: @Eric: Well, I was implicitly assuming that $I_1$ and $I_2$ are intervals, because it is easier to prove in that case and it suffices for this application. If you want to prove (or have a reference for) the general fact that if $E_1,E_2\subseteq \mathbb R$ are measurable, then $|E_1\times E_2|=|E_1||E_2|$, then go ahead and use this. It is enough to handle the case of intervals, because of the reasons given in the first two sentences of my answer, and because a set of outer measure $0$ can be covered by a countable union of open intervals such that the sum of the lengths is arbitrarily small.

Comment: I don't understand why we need to consider $[0,1]$. Why not directly claim that $m^{*}(Z\times E)\le m(Z\times\mathbb R)=m(Z)\times m(\mathbb R)=0\times\infty=0$?

Answer (score 0):

we know that lebesgaue outer mearsure of an countable singelton set zero .so outer measure of (N*N)=o if {(a,b)} can be treated as a singelton  set wehere 'a'and 'b'belongs 'N' wehere 'N' is natural numbers which are countabel.

Comment: this does not really provide an answer to the question... The set in question doesn't have to be singleton or $\Bbb N$ they just have measure $0$ (ex: $\Bbb Q$)...